# Use of ("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName)

Tags: http, http-headers, content-disposition

I have this problem in this piece of code:

```
resp.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
```

When the file name is : a_b_c.doc or abc.doc , the name of the downloaded file is correct.
However, when the file name is : a b c.doc , the name of the downloaded file is only "a".

How can I work around this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Put quotes around the filename like this:

```
resp.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
```

Comment: will help for spaces, but not for non-ASCII characters,

Answer (score -1):

Concatenate the file name after perform the url encode on the file name string.

Answer (score -4):

[The spec explains this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266), and gives explicit examples with spaces in the file name.

Comment: Can you provide the answer instead of just linking to a 14 page spec?